# How to display table row number in the alert

Tags: jquery

Below is my validation function:

```
function validation() {


    alertValidation= "";
        // Note, this is just so it's declared...

    $(".textAreaQuestion").each(function() {
        if (!this.value || this.value.length < 5) {
            alertValidation += "\nYou have not entered a valid Question\n";
        }

            if(alertValidation != ""){ 
                return false;//Stop the each loop 
            } 
    });

        $(".numberAnswerTxtRow").each(function() {

        if (!this.value) {
            alertValidation += "\nPlease Enter in the Number of Answers you Require for this question\n";
        }

    if(alertValidation != ""){ 
                return false;//Stop the each loop 
            } 

    });

        $(".txtWeightRow").each(function() {
        if (!this.value) {
            alertValidation += "\nPlease enter in a figure for Number of Marks for this Question\n";
        }

            if(alertValidation != ""){ 
                return false;//Stop the each loop 
            } 
    });
```

What the code above does is that it displays an alert for each row if there are any errros in the row.

Example:

If in a table row the user has left .textAreaQuestion, .numberAnswerTxtRow and .textWeightRow all empty, then in the alert it will display all of the related messages in one alert like below:

```
You have not entered a valid Question

Please Enter in the Number of Answers you Require for this question

Please enter in a figure for Number of Marks for this Question
```

Now each table row has its own question number (table row number). So what I want to know is that how can I include the question number in the alert so that it states which rows the alert messages are refering to? If it was like the example above I want the alert to be displayed like below:

```
You have errors on question number: 1 // how do I display this line in the alert

You have not entered a valid Question

Please Enter in the Number of Answers you Require for this question

Please enter in a figure for Number of Marks for this Question
```

Below is the code on how the question number is added into each table row:

```
var qnum = 1;

function insertQuestion(form) {  

    var $tbody = $('#qandatbl > tbody'); 
    var $tr = $("<tr class='optionAndAnswer' align='center'></tr>");
    var $qid = $("<td class='qid'>" + qnum + "</td>");

$tr.append($qid);
$tbody.append($tr); 

   $(form).find('.numberOfQuestions').val(qnum);

    ++qnum;
    $("#questionNum").text(qnum);

}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well since you added the class **qid** to the td containing the questionnumber you should be able to access it via `$('td.qid').html()`. This gives you the innerhtml of the td with the class **qid** check [here](http://api.jquery.com/html/) for more info.

**EDIT:**
On second thought `$('td.qid').text()` might be better.